# Re open image after cropping in python pillowPIL?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, crop

*I want to get tilling of an image like diagram below please see image for complete understanding*

[diagram for understanding algorithme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOwdb.png)

**CODE with COMMENTED TROUBLE MAKING LINES**

```
from PIL import Image
import os
from os.path import expanduser
def series():
    # image_name = os.path.basename(image_path)
    # getting image height and width
    image_path = 'sample.jpg'
    with Image.open(image_path) as img:
        width = img.size[0]
        height = img.size[1]
    name = 0
    a = width/4
    i = height/a
    i = int(i)
    print "WIDTH:"+str(width)+" HEIGHT:"+str(height)+" A:"+str(a)+" I:"+str(i)
    x1 = 0
    y1 = 0
    x2 = y2 = a
    for x in range(i):
        for y in range(4):
            # saved_location = "results/" + str(name) + '.jpg'
            # coords = (x1,y1,x2,y2)
            # image_path = 'sample.jpg'
            # imgO = Image.open(image_path)
            # cropped_image = imgO.crop(coords)
            # cropped_image.save(saved_location)
            print "name:" + str(name) + "x1:"+str(x1)+" y1:"+str(y1)+" x2:"+str(x2)+" y2:"+str(y2) + " -- OK"
            x1 = x1 + int(a)
            name = name + 1
        y1 = y1 + int(a)
        x1 = 0

series()
```

**OUTPUT of COMMENTED code**

```
anas@anas-XPS-12-9Q33:~/Desktop/albumTiler$ python tiler.py
WIDTH:1800 HEIGHT:1200 A:450 I:2
name:0x1:0 y1:0 x2:450 y2:450 -- OK
name:1x1:450 y1:0 x2:450 y2:450 -- OK
name:2x1:900 y1:0 x2:450 y2:450 -- OK
name:3x1:1350 y1:0 x2:450 y2:450 -- OK
name:4x1:0 y1:450 x2:450 y2:450 -- OK
name:5x1:450 y1:450 x2:450 y2:450 -- OK
name:6x1:900 y1:450 x2:450 y2:450 -- OK
name:7x1:1350 y1:450 x2:450 y2:450 -- OK
```

this means everything in code is execting and OK

**PROBLEM IS**

> when un-commented the code it crops image from previously cropped image  when cropping for second time and further **I want to re open original image for all crops** *pasting un-commented code results bilow for deep explanation*

```
anas@anas-XPS-12-9Q33:~/Desktop/albumTiler$ python tiler.py
WIDTH:1800 HEIGHT:1200 A:450 I:2
name:0x1:0 y1:0 x2:450 y2:450 -- OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tiler.py", line 33, in <module>
    series()
  File "tiler.py", line 26, in series
    cropped_image.save(saved_location)
  File "/home/anas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1994, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/home/anas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 761, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0, 0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)], bufsize)
  File "/home/anas/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 514, in _save
    e.setimage(im.im, b)
SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image
```

Comment: coordinating is also working right

Answer (score 0):

The crop rectangle, should be  a (left, upper, right, lower)-tuple

instead of

```
coords = (x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

you need use

```
coords = (x1,y1,x1+x2,y1+y2)
```

Comment: Yes,  I have,  locally

Comment: Oh I dont know how that worked but thanks for answering my question

Comment: Thanks for help. God bless you

Comment: x2 and y2 are  width and height,  the crop parameter need right and lower,